# Benefits of Custom Validation attributes over manual validation in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, annotations, data-annotations

What are the benefits to using custom data validations in the form of attributes for our models, versus making those validation checks in the action of the controller?

A small example.

```
public class CollectionHasElementsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is IList<string> stringCollection)
        {
            return stringCollection.Count > 0
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

versus

```
public IActionResult someAction(List<string> stringCollection)
{
    if (stringCollection.Count <= 0)
    {
        // return your error the way you want to here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason would be simplicity and following the principle DRY. Lets say you have 10 controllers which performs your business logic using `List<string> stringCollection` ,now you have to manually write `if()` do this again and again in all 10 Controllers.

With a attribute you just write `if()` only once inside where the validation is done and just add the attribute.

A better alternative to writing your own validation conditions is using a library like `FluentValidation` -> [Docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

If you want to see some more amazing libraries like this, [checkout this list](https://hariharan-subramanian.netlify.com/posts/2020/01/top-nuget-libraries-for-c/)

Comment: I know this is slightly off-topic, but are ValidationAttributes executed in the order you write them over properties/fields/etc, or is it at random?